# Problemas con sublime text y python

Tags: sublimetext3

cuando guardo cambio de cualquier archivo e imprimo en consola me sale lo siguiente:
unable to save direcciones de archivo
Operacion no permitida

Comment: El mensaje te sale en Sublime o al ejecutar en consola. Exactamente cuál es el error que te sale.

Comment: al ejecutar. o cuando guardo cambios con ctlr+ s me manda ese mensaje